# Kotlin ensure a return value for all combinations of enums

Tags: kotlin, enums

Let's say we are a diner and need to a way to return the unique prices for every possible combination of a combo meal.  In code, it would look something like this:

```
enum class Meat{
 Ham, Bacon, Steak
}

enum class Drink{
  Milk, OJ, Coffee, Tea
}

enum class Eggs{
  Scrambled, Fried, Over-Easy
}


fun getComboPrice(meat: Meat, drink: Drink, eggs: Eggs): Double{
   // What goes here?
}
```

I know I can do nested when statements like:

```
when(meat){
  Meat.Ham -> {
       when(drink) {
             ...etc
    }
  }
}
```

But in my real world case I can have 5-6 enums with hundreds of combinations.  That many nested whens is crazy and will be a pain to update.

What I would like to do is something like:

```
data class ComboMeal(val meat: Meat, val drink: Drink, val eggs: Eggs)

var hashMap: HashMap<ComboMeal,  Double> = HashMap<ComboMeal, Double>()
hashMap.put(<Meat.Ham, Drink.Milk, Eggs.Scrambled>, 10.77)
etc.
```

However, I lose my compiler guarantee that all combinations are covered.  Is there any solution that provides both?  A compiler guarantee that all combos are covered without the craziness of 5 nested whens?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way to have the compiler guarantee you've handled every possible combination of three separate types - if you need that guarantee, it would probably be a good idea to write a test that generates every permutation of meals and checks you get something back for each. But generally for this kind of thing you'd provide rules like combining the prices, adding discounts for certain item combos etc - you'd write logic to algorithmically generate a result. If you want to explicitly list every possible combo in a map, that's not a lot different from writing all the `when`s!

Comment: You can also avoid nesting by combining boolean expressions...

Comment: If there are that many combinations, then a real-world application would be better storing it all (whether individual prices or rules) in a database or other resource — especially for values like prices which are likely to change in future.